# Textarea disappears after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I am using the following code to animate the disappearing of a textarea once the control is out of focus and the textarea is empty.

```
$(this).blur(function ()
{
    var value = $(this).val().trim();
    if (value == "")
    {
        // empty; make it disappear
        $(this).animate({
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        }, 1000,'linear',
        function ()
        {$(this).parent().css("display", "none")});
    }
});
```

The box disappears without animation. But if i run the following code the animation is still there:

```
$(this).blur(function ()
{
    var value = $(this).val().trim();
    if (value == "")
    {
        // empty; make it disappear
        $(this).animate({
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

I am not sure why the display:none code is executing before the completion of the animation.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7pbuxtkz/

Comment: It may have something to do with you doing the animation on `$(this)` but then removing the parent of `$(this)` and not `$(this)` itself.

Comment: Replacing $(this).parent().css("display", "none"); with $(this).css("display", "none"); also doesn't help!

Comment: What happens if you specify the selector directly? `$('#myID').css("display", "none");`  ...nvm, just read your question again. It's working, it's just doing it before the animation is over.

Comment: Still the same problem!

Comment: Honestly, I'm stumped why that isn't working for you. You could work around it by putting a timeout in the function, but it doesn't explain your question. `function ()
        { setTimeout(function() {$(this).parent().css("display", "none")}, 1000)};`

Comment: Does it behave differently in different browsers?

Comment: In chrome it hides without animation. In IE, animation happens - but textarea doesn't disappear after animation

Comment: It's also worth checking your css `transition-duration` and make sure it's properly set (or not set at all). Also, what happens if you remove the 'linear' from it? Same thing?

Comment: If you get a chance, do you mind creating a JSFIDDLE of this? That'll help us out a bit with it.

Comment: transition-duration was not set. But the problem exists even after setting the transition-duration of 1s for the textarea

Comment: JS Fiddle worked fine for me. It animates, then it applies `display: none` to `#divinstructions` after the animation is over. I tested it with `linear` set and unset, same results. If you remove the `.parent()` it applies it to the textarea `pinstructions` instead, but runs as it should. This leaves me to believe 1 of 2 possible things... 1) your browser, or 2) your CSS. Just to note, I'm using Chrome and haven't tested it on other browsers. Which browser are you using yourself?

Comment: My jsfiddle is also not working - no animation or disappearing. Does it have something to do with my browser settings?

Comment: In your JSFIDDLE, you forgot to set the framework on the left side. If you click the dropdown and set it to jQuery (whatever version you're using) then it should work fine in FIDDLE, though that's not the issue here unless in your HTML you're not initializing jQuery (but that doesn't seem to be the case). If it works in your FIDDLE for you, but it doesn't work on your own site, then it isn't your browser. If it won't work in either (after you set the framework) then it's your browser.

Comment: I am using chrome. What do u think the css problem could be? 
The css for the textarea is being applied by multiple css files. So there is no way I can post the css classes here.

Comment: (I tested the other browsers, works fine there also) The first thing that comes to mind is something that's changing the transition on it from the CSS side. I got another idea that may help, and it's using `promise()` on it. I'll post it up as an answer and we can discuss it further from there.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. It utilizes the `promise()` and `done()` instead of using it directly from the callback itself. Although your original code works for me, it's worth trying. `Promise()` will ensure that all of the animations are done.

```
$('.notesArea').each(function () {
    $(this).blur(function () {
        var value = $(this).val().trim();
        if (value == "") {
            // empty; make it disappear
            $(this).animate({
                width: 0,
                height: 0
            }, 1000).promise().done(function () {
                $(this).parent().css("visibility", "hidden")
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Let me know how it goes and we'll go from there. As I mentioned before, if this doesn't work, then I feel it's something taking place from your CSS. If that's the case, I'll poke around and see what I can find out for you.

More information on `promise()`: https://api.jquery.com/promise/

I know you said you're using multiple CSS files, which is why you didn't post it here. I would go through those CSS files and see if there is anything that's setting the `transition-duration` on it to something lower than what you're setting your animation's duration to.

Comment: This didnt work. 
But I made a slight change. Instead of setting display as none, I am setting visibility as hidden now. And it works!!!

Comment: That's really bizarre! :D I'm happy that it's working for you now though. I tested visibility on your JSFIDDLE and it works in the same way that display did for me. So either way seems to work effectively for people that'll use your site. I'll update my answer so anyone else that reads this thread can give it a try.